# error while adding data to href

Tags: java, html, jsp

The following jsp snippet :

```
<% while(set.next()) { %>

<li>
         <%-- statement 3--%> <a class="thumb" href="/home/non-admin/project uploads/project users/" <% + %> <%= set.getString("UserEmail") %> <% + %> "/" <% + %> <%= set.getString("NameOfThePhoto") %> > <img src="images/portfolio_two/1_thumb.jpg" alt="one"> </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-title portfolio_two">&quot;Pier by the sea, Fowey, Cornwall, UK&quot;</div>
          </div>
</li>
<% } %>
```

gives an error in the statement 3 . The IDE says `not a statement` and `"""""" is  not serializable in xml 1.0`. what is this error and why does it occur ?
In the statement 3 i am adding the vales fetched from the database to href.

Comment: What's up with all those `<% + %>`? How is that a valid statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a shot. But, I still don't like the spaces in "project uploads" and "project users".

```
href="/home/non-admin/project uploads/project users/<%=set.getString("UserEmail")%>/<%=set.getString("NameOfThePhoto")%>"
```